# How to convert html color names into RGB values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, colors, rubygems

I know there is a gem called [Color](http://rubydoc.info/gems/color/1.4.1/frames). I installed it.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to use the thing.

I just want to convert a color name into its RGB values, if possible without copying the whole color table into my code.

I want to be able to convert something like `red` or `Navy` into three numeric values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
require 'color/css'
red_code = Color::CSS["red"].html
#=> "#ff0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just came across this gem in a current project and had to do the same. I needed RBG values like OP asked for and so I used the `css_rbg` instance method similar to how tokland produced the hex value with the `html` instance method.

```
require 'color/css'
red_code = Color::CSS["red"].css_rgb
#=> "rgb(100.00%, 0.00%, 0.00%)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Html colours are expressed as an Hexadecimal colour, and it turns out that a RGB colour is not more than a Hexadecimal expression of the colour so:

```
#ff0000 = r:255 g:0 b:0
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question.